# How to execute procedure from List with parameters in Progress 4gl?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I have some list like this

```
DEFINE VARIABLE procedurelist AS CHARACTER EXTENT 5
    INITIAL [ "1.p", "2.p", "3.p", "4.p", "5.p"].
```

but this all procedures with input-output parameters and i want to execute this procedure, How can i do this? I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The base of your solution is the `RUN VALUE` statement.

The manual states.

> VALUE( extern-expression ) An expression that returns the name of the (local or remote) external procedure you want to run....

This basically means that you can input a string with the value of a program (or procedure) into your RUN statement.

If all input-output parameters are exactly the same you can do like this:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE procedurelist AS CHARACTER EXTENT 5 INITIAL [ "1.p", "2.p", "3.p", "4.p", "5.p"].

DEFINE VARIABLE iExtent   AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cVariable AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.

DO iExtent = 1 TO EXTENT(procedurelist):
    RUN VALUE(procedurelist[iExtent]) (INPUT-OUTPUT cVariable).
END.
```

If the parameters are different it gets trickier (but not impossible). The `CREATE CALL` and the Call Object can help you there. In this case you would need some kind of way to keep track of the different parameters as well.

Here's a basic example taken directly from the online help:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE hCall AS HANDLE NO-UNDO. 

CREATE CALL hCall. 
/* Invoke hello.p non-persistently */
hCall:CALL-NAME      = "hello.p".

/* Sets CALL-TYPE to the default */
hCall:CALL-TYPE  = PROCEDURE-CALL-TYPE.
hCall:NUM-PARAMETERS = 1.
hCall:SET-PARAMETER(1, "CHARACTER", "INPUT", "HELLO WORLD").
hCall:INVOKE. 

/* Clean up */
DELETE OBJECT hCall.
```